# How Implement Date when the object created in Java?

Tags: java, object, date, gettime

It's an homework. 
I have to implement the following:

private Date dateCreated which store, when the object was created.

```
private Date dateCreated;
```

getter method for dateCreated.

```
public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}
```

And must implement this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Account a=new Account(1122,20000,4.5);
    a.withdraw(2500);
    a.deposit(3000);
    System.out.println(a.getBalance());
    System.out.println(a.getMonthlyInterestRate()+"%");
    System.out.println(a.getDateCreated()); // or another method what can get 
       //time  when the object created
}
```

I've tried use the getTime() but I don't know how can I use in my code.
I saw some solution, but it always created an another classes for this.
I would like a simple solution. (maybe when declare the dateCreated field)

Comment: Thanks everybody the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `dateCreated` in the constructor of `Account`, to capture when it was created like this:

```
public Account(...<params>...)
{
   ... <usual param initialization that you already have>  ...
   this.dateCreated = new Date(); // sets to the current date/time
}
```

OR, you could explicitly set it (provided you have a setter exposed):

```
a.setDateCreated(new Date());
```

Your getter `getDateCreated()` should then give you the desired value.

Comment: Nice, I like your way how initialize the dateCreated in the Constructor

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
private Date dateCreated = new Date();
```

it will be initialised with the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the Date in the constructor, via new Date(). It creates a Date with the time you called the constructor.